# Creating tables with spanning rows/columns

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a table which looks like

[image: this]

but I'm not really sure how to incorporate multiple spanning rows and columns together (to add 'Organism 1' and 'Organism 2'). I've gotten to this point so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}
 &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$T$} \\cline{2-3}
$S$ & $a,a$ & $b,c$ \\cline{2-3}
$T$ & $c,b$ & $d,d$ \\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And it currently looks like this:

[image: column spanning table]

Can anyone suggest how to add the top 'Organism 2' and left 'Organism 1' row/column entries?

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! I added your picture inline, which is preferable to links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks Seamus! I initially tried adding the images inline but I couldn't as I needed a minimum of 10 points. BTW, could you please embed the first image too (in the first line)?

Comment: @Seasmus,@Nishant: I did included the first image now. The in-text reference was not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

starting from your code, I got to this:

[image]

Basically, I have added the package `multirow` and changed the `cline` indexes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cr|c|c|}
  \multicolumn{2}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Organism 2} \\

  \multicolumn{2}{r}{}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S$}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$T$} \\

  \cline{3-4}


  \multirow{2}{*}{Organism 1} & $S$ & $a,a$ & $b,c$ \\
  \cline{3-4}

 & $T$ & $c,b$ & $d,d$ \\
  \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
                        &     & \Block{1-2}{Organism 2} \\
                        &     & $S$      & $T$ \\
\Block{2-1}{Organism 1} & $S$ & \Block[hvlines]{2-2}{}
                                $a$, $a$ & $b$, $c$  \\
                        & $T$ & $c$, $b$ & $d$, $d$ \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]