# How can I typeset a table whose lines do not extend to row and column headings?

Tags: tables

Is there an easy way to convert this table (with complete lines)

[image: completelines]

into that one (with incomplete lines; the image is "Photoshopped" for illustration)?

[image: incompletelines]

Note that I want to get rid of the initial part of the lines (vertical and horizontal).
All solutions are welcomed but I would prefer a solution that doesn't require additional packages, if possible.

This is the code for the first image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|}
  & A & B \\ \hline
a & 0  & 1 \\ \hline
b & 10 & 11\\ \hline
c & 20 & 21\\ \hline
d & 30 & 31\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apart from the recommendation about vertical lines, what about `\cline{}` and `\multicolumn{}` approach?

Comment: This may come in handy: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: Related question (starts with a solution to your exact question) [Creating tables with spanning rows/columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11934). See also [Making an odd shaped table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62484)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use (if needed at all) `\multicolumn{1}{c}{A}` etc. for the centered header cells or `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0}` etc. for the data cells, if `\begin{tabular}{lcc}` is used, i.e. without the vertical lines, but this would involve many cell entries to be changed.

Restricting horizontal lines to particular columns can be done with `\cline{2-3}` for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} \\ 
\cline{2-3}
a & 0  & 1 \\ 
\cline{2-3}
b & 10 & 11\\
\cline{2-3}
c & 20 & 21\\ 
\cline{2-3}
d & 30 & 31\\ 
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note**: The usage of vertical lines in tables is discouraged, the number of horizontal lines should be limited to a minimum

Answer (score 3):

It's rather simple:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A }& \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} \\
  \cline{2-3}
a & 0  & 1 \\
  \cline{2-3}
b & 10 & 11\\
  \cline{2-3}
c & 20 & 21\\
  \cline{2-3}
d & 30 & 31\\
  \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]